# Bootstrap btn-group-justified

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have code html bootstrap, but when display incorrect.enter image description here
[code bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ftg.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Home" />
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Cart" />
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Products" />
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Contact Us" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[when display on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW5NS.png)

Comment: Can you post the code as text?

Comment: You click on code bootstrap to display image. I am not english. Thanks.

Comment: Tests fine locally for me. Are you sure bootstrap.min.js is being loaded? Check dev tools and make sure you don't see a 404.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your bootstrap css is either not being included or you have some other css overriding it.

Translated from Google:

> Nó xuất hiện "bootstrap.css" hoặc là không được bao gồm hoặc bạn có một số css khác ghi đè lên nó.

ASPX Markup:

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <asp:Button  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Home" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Cart" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <asp:Button  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Products" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Contact Us" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Renders HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" value="Home" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl01" value="Cart" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl02" value="Products" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl03" value="Contact Us" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Run the snippet and you can see it works.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" value="Home" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl01" value="Cart" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl02" value="Products" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl03" value="Contact Us" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi.
If I use of you:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
then true.
But if I use:
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
then false.

Comment: if false then why? maybe change `<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`  to `<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`